# Placeholder not working in IE8 & IE9, even using a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, placeholder

I'm using the following plugin to show the placeholder in IE8 and IE9. I think it worked the last year, and at this moment it isn't:

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder

Actually, this plugin works perfect at the demo page: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder

I really don't know how to fix it. I'm using it in WordPress, where I load the local jQuery, which is normally the last version if I remember it well. I enqueue the scripts on functions.php:

```
function szt_load_scripts() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
wp_enqueue_style( 'shortcodes', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/shortcodes.css' );

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

if ( is_singular() ) { 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); 
}

if (ot_get_option('szt_enable_linkbuilding') === "on") {
    wp_deregister_script( 'link-building-pro-min' );
    wp_register_script( 'link-building-pro-min', get_template_directory_uri().'/jquery/link-building-pro/link-building-pro-min.js', array(), true, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'link-building-pro-min' );
}

wp_enqueue_script('scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/jquery/scripts.js');
wp_localize_script('scripts', 'contactForm', array(
    'youForgot' => __('<span class="errormsg">You forgot to enter your ', 'wptheme'),
    'invalidEmail' => __('<span class="errormsg">You entered an invalid email.</span>', 'wptheme'),
    'messageSent' => __('<p class="thanks"><strong>Thanks!</strong> Your message was successfully sent.</p>', 'wptheme')
));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'szt_load_scripts');
```

Am I loading the plugin in a wrong way?
Do I need to use an older version of jQuery?
Will I need to add a different fix for that?

Comment: What do you see (if anything) in the error console?

Comment: Can you go to the page and view source to make sure the script is even being added to the page? Also just adding the script alone is not enough, you also need to run `$('input, textarea').placeholder();` inside a `document.ready`.

Comment: I don't know how to use the error console, @TiesonT.

Comment: @Gerard Press the F12 key.

Comment: @TiesonT. it has one error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined measureIt.js:120 (anonymous function)". But it belongs to the file measureIt.js, which is not of the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the plugin inside (document).ready().

Comment: Ahm, what I did is to insert `$('input, textarea').placeholder();` after the plugin. I guess it's wrong. Should it be `$(document).ready(function() { $('input, textarea').placeholder(); });`. I'm gonna test it.

Comment: It's still not working. Probably I'm missing something. Anyway I think you are right in your answer. I vote it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Anyway you have some errors on your console. It will be helpfull you to fix it.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm good copying and pasting code but I really don't know how to debug JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @Genethic, I found one error when I click the search button (and it displays a popup): `positionPopup();`. Did you find more errors? As I can see, the console only debugs the code when it needs to be executed (on Google Chrome and Firefox). I deduce, then, that the solution is to test all the functions, one by one. Is it right?